# Android App Development

Tags: java, android

I am a Java beginner , I want to develop Android app , what all is essential to learn in Java before I start developing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to find a good book on Android and while you are reading it, if there is something you don't understand, about Java, then you will need to learn that.

It really depends on what you are doing in your application. For example, are you doing games, then OpenGL is needed, but if you are just doing a basic application then the bar for what is needed is much lower.

As a minimum, go through the Sun Java Tutorial (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/) and make certain you understand the language basics.

Beyond that, if you described in broad strokes what you are attempting it would be easier to answer.

Comment: Is leraning Swings and AWT required ?

Comment: No not for android programming

Comment: The layout in Android is not swing or awt, but some of the concepts, in terms of panels within panels may be useful, so some concept of that could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just the Java Basics will be sufficient as far as i know!!! Just understanding Java and doing a thorough study of Android related books - such as "Apress - Beginning Android" or the more famous Mark Murphy's "The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development" will be sufficient!